# Empty array returned after os.path.join

Tags: python

I am trying to read json files. file.readlines() returns an empty array so can't work with it.

```
path= 'C:/Ujjwal/Python for Beginners - Scripting Programming/extract_test_setup/json'
files = filter(lambda x: os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x)), os.listdir(path))
# Sort list of files based on last modification time in ascending order
files = sorted(files,key = lambda x: -os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, x)))
print(files)

for loop in files:
    # print(loop)
    with open(loop) as file:


          lines = file.readlines()
          print(lines)
```

Comment: Have you checked what `os.listdir(path)` returns?

Comment: Sanity check: *path* is a directory, you want to get all plain files from that directory and process them in reverse order of their modification time. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein. Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import join, isfile, getmtime
from sys import stderr

path = 'C:/Ujjwal/Python for Beginners - Scripting Programming/extract_test_setup/json'

files = [file for file in glob(join(path, '*')) if isfile(file)]

for file in sorted(files, key=lambda _: getmtime(_), reverse=True):
    try:
        with open(file) as data:
            pass # do something with the file
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=stderr)
```

Comment: The problem is different here. I am interested in parsing contents of json file and not just printing directory/file name.

Comment: @uds Look at my answer again and note where it says "do something with the file". That's where you process the file. Also, there are no *print()* statements in my answer